# $wp_query code not displaying correctly

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have recently made a wordpress movie website from scratch, of which I am now finding it hard to iron out the code that is not working.
The problem I have is I have a custom post type "movies" and some custom metadata attached to the afore mentioned post type, what I want to do is list my custom post type "movies" in orderby the metadata "released". This is part of my functions.php file.

```
add_filter( 'rwmb_meta_boxes', 'your_prefix_meta_boxes' );

function your_prefix_meta_boxes( $meta_boxes ) {
$meta_boxes[] = array(
    'title'      => __( 'Movie Meta Box', 'textdomain' ),
    'post_types' => 'movies',
    'fields'     => array(
        array(
            'id'   => 'name',
            'name' => __( 'Title', 'textdomain' ),
            'type' => 'text',
        ),
        array(
            'id'   => 'released',
            'name' => __( 'Release Date', 'textdomain' ),
            'type' => 'date',
        ),
        array(
            'id'      => 'rating',
            'name'    => __( 'Rating', 'textdomain' ),
            'type'    => 'radio',
            'options' => array(
                '0' => __( 'Unrated', 'textdomain' ),
                '1' => __( '1', 'textdomain' ),
                '2' => __( '2', 'textdomain' ),
                '3' => __( '3', 'textdomain' ),
                '4' => __( '4', 'textdomain' ),
                '5' => __( '5', 'textdomain' ),
                '6' => __( '6', 'textdomain' ),
                '7' => __( '7', 'textdomain' ),
                '8' => __( '8', 'textdomain' ),
                '9' => __( '9', 'textdomain' ),
                '10' => __( '10', 'textdomain' ),
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'id'   => 'duration',
            'name' => __( 'Duration', 'textdomain' ),
            'type' => 'text',
        ),
        array(
            'id'      => 'genre',
            'name'    => __( 'Genre', 'textdomain' ),
            'type'    => 'textarea',
        ),
        array(
            'id'   => 'director',
            'name' => __( 'Director/s', 'textdomain' ),
            'type' => 'textarea',
        ),
        array(
            'id'   => 'writer',
            'name' => __( 'Writer/s', 'textdomain' ),
            'type' => 'textarea',
        ),
        array(
            'id'   => 'stars',
            'name' => __( 'Star/s', 'textdomain' ),
            'type' => 'textarea',
        ),
        array(
            'id'   => 'storyline',
            'name' => __( 'Storyline', 'textdomain' ),
            'type' => 'textarea',
        ),
    ),
);
return $meta_boxes;
}
```

And this is the archives-movies.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php bd_pagination(); ?>

<div class="row" role="main"><!-- ROW -->

<?php

$args = array(

        "posts_per_page"    => 10,
        "post_type"         => "movies",
        "post_status"       => "publish",
        "meta_key"          => "released",
        "orderby"           => "meta_value_num",
        "order"             => "DESC"

        );

$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>

<?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

<div class="col-lg-9">

<div class="panel panel-default panel-body" style="padding-bottom:0;"><!-- PANEL -->

<p class="fa fa-calendar"></p>&nbsp;<?php the_time( 'd-m-Y' ); ?> | <p class="fa fa-clock-o"></p> <?php the_time( 'H:i a' ); ?> |&nbsp;<p class="fa fa-user"></p>&nbsp;<a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a></i> |&nbsp;<p class="fa fa-envelope-o"></p>&nbsp;posted in movies

<article class="post <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>has-thumbnail <?php } ?>">

    <div class="post-thumbnail">

        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'image-poster' ); ?></a>

    </div>

    <article class="post-thumbnail-text">

        <h4 class="align_Center" style="color:#000; padding-bottom:1em;">

            <?php the_title(); ?>

        </h4>

        <?php 

            $nam = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "name", true );
            $rel = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "released", true );
            $rat = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "rating", true );
            $dur = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "duration", true );
            $gen = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "genre", true );
            $dir = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "director", true );
            $wri = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "writer", true );
            $sta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "stars", true );
            $sto = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "storyline", true );

        ?>

        <div class="align_Left">

            <p><b>Title:</b>&nbsp;<?php echo $nam; ?></p>
            <p><b>Released:</b>&nbsp;<?php echo $rel; ?></p>
            <p><b>Rating:</b>&nbsp;<?php echo $rat; ?>/10</p>
            <p><b>Duration:</b>&nbsp;<?php echo $dur; ?>&nbsp;min</p>
            <p><b>Genre:</b>&nbsp;<?php echo $gen; ?></p>
            <p><b>Director/s:</b>&nbsp;<?php echo $dir; ?></p>
            <p><b>Writer/s:</b>&nbsp;<?php echo $wri; ?></p>
            <p><b>Stars:</b>&nbsp;<?php echo $sta; ?></p>

        </div>

    </article>

</article>

<br>

<div class="panel panel-default panel-body" style="padding:20px 20px 10px 20px">

    <p><b>Storyline:</b>&nbsp;<?php echo $sto; ?></p>

</div>

</div><!-- /PANEL -->

</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : echo '<p>NO CONTENT FOUND</p>'; ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>

</div><!-- /ROW -->

<?php bd_pagination(); ?>

<br>

</div><!-- ./CONTAINER --> 

<?php get_template_part( 'Secondfooter' ); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Hope someone can help me .. been @ it for weeks.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Did you try using meta_value instead meta_value_num in query?

Comment: Offhand the issue is likely to be in your save meta boxes function, you have date specified in your array to set up but if you check the db post meta, its probably saved as text format, you need to convert to timestamp (`strtotime()` should work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use `meta_type` to define the right type:**

```
'meta_key'  => 'released',
'meta_type' => 'DATE',
'orderby'   => 'meta_value_date',
'order'     => 'DESC'
```

(this example assumes using DATE format)

---

> `meta_value` - Note that a `meta_key=keyname` must also be present in the query. Note also that the sorting will be alphabetical which is fine for strings (i.e. words), but can be unexpected for numbers (e.g. 1, 3, 34, 4, 56, 6, etc, rather than 1, 3, 4, 6, 34, 56 as you might naturally expect). Use `meta_value_num` instead for numeric values. You may also specify `meta_type` if you want to cast the meta value as a specific type. Possible values are `NUMERIC`, `BINARY`, `CHAR`, `DATE`, `DATETIME`, `DECIMAL`, `SIGNED`, `TIME`, `UNSIGNED`, same as in `$meta_query`. When using `meta_type` you can also use meta_value_* accordingly. For example, when using DATETIME as `meta_type` you can use `meta_value_datetime` to define order structure.

Read more about that here: [Orderby_Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)